# Linking Issues of one git repository to commits of another repository

Tags: git, github, repository

I have two projects "project-A" and "project-B". The issues are being reported in "project-A" but the actual development is going on in "project-B".

Referring "project-A" in every commit comment is challenging. I am exploring for a better option to link the issues of "project-A" to be linked to "project-B" code commits. A simple ask is if the developer commits with a comment "#23 fixed" in 'project-B', it should be visible in 'project-A's relevant issue comment history.

Comment: do you referring project-A and project-B as branches of same repo or different repo with same content ?

Comment: No, both of them are completely different repositories but within the same organization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Transforming git commit messages:**

From your workspace

```
$ cd myrepo
$ vi .git/hooks/commit-msg
```

Note that this is a client side hook. Now add the following content to it

```
#!/bin/sh
projecta_issues_link="https:\/\/github.com\/git\/git\/issues\/"

message=`cat $1 | sed "s/projecta/${projecta_issues_link}/g"`
echo ${message} > $1
exit 0
```

Then make a change to any file, and commit it with the following message:

```
git commit -m "This fixes projecta#1234"
```

Your commit message should be transformed to a link now.

**2. Applying the client side hook on all repositories:**

There's a really well-written answer to that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11327092/1110636).

Answer (score 1):

You can link to a commit or issue in a different repository by writing out its full GitHub URL. GitHub will shorten it appropriately when displaying it.

This works throughout the GitHub UI, including commit messages.

Comment: What do you mean by writing out its full URL? Can you pls explain?

Comment: Ok, adding that in every commit / issue is challenging. We have many issues and many commits everyday. I am exploring for a better option.

Comment: Perhaps this is an indicator that your workflow or project structure could be modified to make it less complex?

Comment: When the project began we setup repo project-A and it was communicated to client. But later due to some issues we had to create another repo project-B and after sometime we realized client was using project-A repo for logging issues. We don't want to ask client to change the repo & I am now tasked to look out a way to link both of them!!

Answer (score 1):

> When the project began we setup repo project-A and it was communicated to client.
>
> But later due to some issues we had to create another repo project-B and after sometime we realized client was using project-A repo for logging issues.
> We don't want to ask client to change the repo

Thant means `project-A` can reference `project-B` as a submodule.
Not for the `project-B` sources, but for the ability to record the state of `project-B` main SHA1 as a commit in `project-A` repo.
And the comment of that commit (in the parent repo `project-A`) can be made automatically the one of the last commit of `project-B`.

So if a developer makes a new commit "Fix#123" in `project-B`, `project-A` can then automatically record a new commit, with the latest of `project-B` ([tracking a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309): `git submodule update --remote`), with as a comment the comment of the last commit of `project-B`: "Fix#123".

Answer (score 1):

> No, both of them are completely different repositories but within the
>   same organization

Seems only way to do this, is create a github bot or tweak around existing CI's such as travis, and close issue on other respository, if they are closed in commits of your current one.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any means for cross-referencing projects to reflect commits in the manner you are describing:

> link the issues of "project-A" to be linked to "project-B" code commits.

I will state the obvious:

- What are describing is maintaining a release branch "project-A"
- And a development branch as "project-B"

Even though perforce is not git, I have found the ["perforce best practices"](https://www.perforce.com/pdf/scm-best-practices.pdf) paper to be the best description of how to maintain release and development branch sanity. Go directly to page 4 and begin reading there.

As you fix bugs in your customer facing "project-A", which is maintained on a release branch, merge those changes to master as described in the reference document.

I am far less in favor of ["git flow"](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) but I might as well mention it.

Bottom line: You cannot get there from here. There is not a solution to your problem within the scope of any source control I have ever used to the best of my knowledge (subversion, ClearCase, perforce, git).

Since your customer facing project-A has priority (based on my reading of other comments) you will want to bring project-B into project-A's repo.

This will constitute its own challenge, and based on that, using git-flow might suit your needs as you would be bring project-B in as the develop branch.

The difficulty of doing so is dependent on:

1. How much divergence there is between the 2 projects.
2. How familiar you are with git itself.

However, the sooner you tackle the problem, the sooner to eliminate a major pain point for your team.

Answer (score 1):

You can commit issue address directly.

```
git commit -m "This fixes https://github.com/auser/projecta/issues/1234"
```