# link to issue from a commit in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, issue-tracking

I am trying to link an issue from the commit message to a bit bucket issue tracker.

Here is the facts:

1. The people who needs access to issue tracker are different from the developers so I created a new repository so I can give permission to code and issues separately.
2. I need to create a link in code repository so when I enter something such as issue #1234, it generate a link to issue tracker and the issue(such as bitbucket/myname/isseu_tracker/isses/1234
3. I searched and found this information: https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/link-to-bitbucket-issue-tracker-from-commits-296911608.html but I can not find advanced in my repository setting.
4. I found the link in the workflow section of the code repository, but it only works with repository issue tracker and not another repository issues tracker.

Can somebody help me to understand how I can do this?

The other question did not solve my problem as

1. The other question is about github and my question is about bitbucket
2. the other question solution was to use a sub-module, which is not valid here as there are already some ways to create links between issue trackers and commits, but the solution works only on one repository.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50000845

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking Issues of one git repository to commits of another repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607683/linking-issues-of-one-git-repository-to-commits-of-another-repository)